# Alfresco webscript to get the list of all files and folder with their size

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, web-scripting

Need a js based alfresco webscript to get the list of all folders and files recursively alond with their size.

Comment: Won't that be horribly horribly slow on big installs?

Comment: yes i am sure it would be, but we need it for one time analysis

Answer (score 3):

CMIS Query:

```
select cmis:objectId, cmis:name, cmis:contentStreamLength 
from cmis:document 
where cmis:contentStreamLength>0 
order by cmis:contentStreamLength desc
```

- HTTP GET:

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/
    ?cmisselector=query
    &succinct=true
    &q=select cmis:objectId, cmis:name, cmis:contentStreamLength from cmis:document where cmis:contentStreamLength>0 order by cmis:contentStreamLength desc
  ```
- JavaScript:

  Use search [root object](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html):

  > [**search** - org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/Search.html) -
  >   Root object providing access to the various Alfresco search interfaces
  >   such as FTS-Alfresco, Lucene, XPath, and Saved Search results

  ```
  var rs=search.query({
      query:"select * from cmis:document where cmis:contentStreamLength>0 order by cmis:contentStreamLength desc",
      language:"cmis-alfresco"         
  });

  for (var r in rs){
      logger.log(rs[r].parent.nodeRef.id+"/"+rs[r].nodeRef.id+"\t"+rs[r].parent.name+"/"+rs[r].name+"\t"+rs[r].size);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but

i am a beginner in alfresco webscripting and have no idea how to execute this.
i have explored some tutorials on alfresco like 
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/ws-folderListing-intro.html

which involve :-
1. a js file 
2. a free marker template
3. a descriptor xml file

we create and register these in alfresco 
and hit through url and get the things.

Is it possible to have my question solved by such a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: This query only gets the documents. Not the folders

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
you can get the all folders,subfolders,and all the files using repository javascript
Please try this code give proper path values

```
var path="Data Dictionary/***";
var documentLibrary = companyhome.childByNamePath("path");

var children = documentLibrary.children;

traverse(children);

function traverse(nodes){
  for each(var node in nodes) {
    if (node.isContainer){
      logger.log(node.name + " is a folder, traversing down");
      traverse(node.children);
    }else {
      logger.log(node.name ); 
        logger.log(node.size); 
    }
  }
}
```